# What is the best way to upgrade gRPC for PHP?

Tags: php, grpc

I am running gRPC on PHP in production using the PECL extension, along with the PECL installation of Protobuf. I am running on PECL extension version 1.33.1 and I now need to upgrade to 1.37.0. One thing that isn't clear from the documentation is the difference in purpose between the Composer package and the PECL installation, and what is the best way to upgrade. Do I need to keep the version number of the Composer `grpc/grpc` package up-to-date with the PECL extension manually, or will Composer keep it up-to-date if I run `composer update`? Does the version of the Composer package correspond exactly with the PECL extension?

I know composer can force version constraints using `ext-grpc` in the composer.json file, but I can't see that this is done when I view the source at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-php

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.7.0"
        ...
    }
}
```

and the output of `php -i | grep grpc`:

```
grpc support => enabled
grpc module version => 1.33.1
grpc.enable_fork_support => 0 => 0
grpc.grpc_trace => no value => no value
grpc.grpc_verbosity => no value => no value
grpc.log_filename => no value => no value
grpc.poll_strategy => no value => no value
```

Comment: Hey Karim, did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same question now as I'm unsure from the documentation.

Comment: Sort of. It looks like the composer package is a wrapper around the pecl extension. The answer is you do need to keep them both at the same version, so it’s a case of updating both at the same time. 

Why it’s structured this way, I don’t know. My best guess is it’s more maintainable to have the pecl extension be a dumb wrapper around an existing C library and the Composer package doing most of the heavy lifting for the actual calls in PHP.